# Strange, Unexpected change in a literal value (of type double)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, double, constants

I feel like there is a simple solution here, but I just can't seem to find it. I have a constant literal 0.05. Throughout the execution of my program, I've found that the double constant is being treated not as 0.05, but as 0.049999...etc.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

-Matt

PS - I would post a snapshot to give more information, but apparently I can't because I'm a new user... Rats.

Comment: Which language?  And usually a "double" is a approximation, not a exact value.

Comment: C# in Visual Studio 2010. I've found that the issue is actually with my modulo operation I'm performing. 1.7 % 0.05 returns 0.0499999999... rather than 0.

Comment: oops I think I mix up float and double. I suggest to check/search about float arithmetic precision.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think you're on to something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no binary representation of 0.05, because 1/20 is not a power of two, so floating point (double precision) representation only approximates it. 0.5, on the other hand, can be represented exactly.

If v is your literal, then (v == 0.05) should be 'true'